# On what condition on $L$, there exists unit vector $x$, such that $\Re(x^∗Lx)<0$ and $\Im(x^∗Lx)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Given $L\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

Question 1: On what condition on $L$, there exists unit vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, such that

1. $x^*L^*Lx=1$.

Question 2: On what condition on $L$, there exists unit vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, such that

2. $\Re(x^∗Lx)<0$ and $\Im(x^∗Lx)=0$, simultaneously.

---

For question 1, I think the necessary and sufficient condition is that singular values of $L$ are spread across $1$. If singular values of $L$ are all less than $1$, then $\max_{x}x^*L^*Lx=\sigma_{max}(L)<1$. Similarly, if singular values of $L$ are all greater than $1$, then $\min_{x}x^*L^*Lx=\sigma_{min}(L)>1$.

For question 2, lets separate $L$ to hermitian part $L_H=(L+L^*)/2$ and skew-hermitian part $L_S=(L-L^*)/2$, then $L=L_H+L_S$. So $\Re(x^∗Lx)<0$ and $\Im(x^∗Lx)=0$, is equivalent to $x^*L_Hx<0$ and $x^*L_Sx=0$.

I think that $x^*L_Hz<0$ is equivalent to $L_H$ having at least one negative eigenvalue, while $x^*L_Sx=0$ is equivalent to $L_S$ having its eigenvalues spread across $0$. However, I am unable to combine these two observations and find simple condition on $L$ like in question 1.

Comment: Your first answer is correct : We need to have $\|Lx\|^2 = 1$, where $\|v\| = v^*v = \sum_{i} |v_i|^2$ is the complex vector norm. Note that $\|L\cdot\| : S_n \to \mathbb R^+$ is a continuous function, where $S_n$ is the unit ball of $\mathbb C^n$. As $S_n$ is connected, the image of $\|Lx\|^2$ is an interval. Therefore, for the first one occurs if and only if you have $\min_{\|y\| = 1} \|Lx\| \leq 1 \leq \max_{\|y\| = 1} \|Ly\|$, as you mention. For the second, note that you need the *same* $x$ to satisfy the condition for $L_H$ and $L_S$, so it's quite difficult to work with.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you!